# Found a random plus sign, no syntax error

Tags: java, android, eclipse

So, i was looking over some earlier code and found this random plus sign that should have been a syntax error, but the code worked fine and i don't get why

```
tv_distance.setText("Distance: " + 
        ( dist >= 1000 ? (String.format("%.1f", dist/1000f)) : +dist )
        + " " + metric );
```

The extra plus sign is at the third operand of the ternary operator:

```
() ? () : +dist
```

So what am i missing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`dist` is a number.  The `+` is just specifying the sign.  For example, `+5` is always the same as `5` but it is legal.  Obviously, you're much more familiar with its opposite, as in `-5`.

Comment: Exactly `String s = "test "+ +3;`

Answer (score 3):

In this case, the plus sign is being used as a unary operator - redundant here, but included in java to be thought of in the same way as you would a unary subtraction operator, i.e.

```
int x = -5;
```

Comment: It's also fun to do `a + + + + + + + b` and get `a + b`